# How to compare Dropbox revisions

Tags: android, comparison, dropbox, revision

In my application's dropbox integration, I call `metadata` for a file. Inside response, I get the field `rev` which states the **revision** of file. If I modify my file, the revision value updates - which is normal.

The confusion arises when I need to compare between two revisions in order to synchronize my file. How do I know which revision value is the latest/recent one? Is there any logic behind the building of dropbox revision number? Should I take it as **hex** value and perform the comparison?

```
//sample revision values
44de050448f6
44e2050448f6
44e5050448f6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is figure out the order of the revisions, you could call `/revisions` and get the list that way.

Comment: I'm using dropbox's android sdk in which the **revision** field is deprecated. Instead they offer **rev** (a new format of revision) which is based on alphanumeric characters - like the ones I mentioned in my question.

Comment: How can I get the list of revisions through their android sdk? I couldn't find any support for that.

Comment: Which Android SDK are you using? The Core or Sync? In the Android Core SDK, the method is `DropboxAPI.revisions(path, revLimit)`. The Sync SDK has a somewhat different model, and I don't believe it exposes a call to list a file's revisions.

Comment: I'm using **Core**. Ahh now i see what you are pointing towards. Let me try that :)